# D3 translation relative to rotation

Tags: d3.js, trigonometry

Does D3 have a built in way to translate an object location relative to its rotation?

For example, I have a rectangle that's 50x50, located at coordinates (100, 100).  The rectangle is rotated 45 degrees.  I want to move it 100 units "forward".

I can do the trig by hand to figure it out, as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/6530/

```
function toRadians (angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("g");



svg.append('rect').attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50).attr('fill', 'blue')
    .attr('transform', "translate(100, 100) rotate(45)");

var h = 100;
var angle = 45;
var o = Math.sin(toRadians(angle)) * h;
var a = Math.cos(toRadians(angle)) * h
console.log(o)


svg.append('rect').attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50).attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('transform', "translate(100, 100) rotate(45)")
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + (h + o) + ", " + (h + a)  +") rotate(45)");
```

However it seems like a common use case.  Before I start writing up libraries to handle the calculations I'd need, does d3 support anything like this through a native function, or through a popular and well maintained addon?

Answer (score 2):

No, D3 doesn't have anything explicitly for this. However, you can do this easily by nesting multiple elements, no need for trigonometry:

```
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");
g.append('rect').attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50).attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('transform', "rotate(45)");
g.transition().duration(1000)
  .attr('transform', "translate(200,200)");
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/6533/).

Comment: Oops, you answered the same answer while I was answering. Don't you ever sleep? :P

Comment: I don't sleep. I wait ;)

Comment: OK... So... your profile pic is actually a pic of you "sleeping" I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can get the browser to figure it out for you by wrapping the rectangle in a `g` element...

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("g");



svg.attr('transform', "translate(100, 10) rotate(45)")
    .append('rect').attr('width', 50).attr('height', 50).attr('fill', 'blue')
 .transition().duration(2000)
 .attr('transform', "translate(100, 0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```